# Negative output value in "Euclidean loss layer"

Tags: caffe

I am getting negative  output value in `EuclideanLoss` layer in caffe.

I am using following [prototxt](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/mnist_autoencoder.prototxt) file:

```
examples/mnist/mnist_autoencoder.prototxt
```

The last 3 layers are given below:

```
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"
  bottom: "decode1"
  bottom: "flatdata"
  top: "cross_entropy_loss"
  loss_weight: 1
}
layer {
  name: "decode1neuron"
  type: "Sigmoid"
  bottom: "decode1"
  top: "decode1neuron"
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "decode1neuron"
  bottom: "flatdata"
  top: "l2_error"
  loss_weight: 0
}
```

As the final layer type is `EuclideanLoss` I am expecting  a positive value. But the layer outputs are negative sometimes.

```
  net_->Forward();
  Blob<float>* output_layer = net_->output_blobs()[0];
  const float* begin = output_layer->cpu_data();
  const float* end = begin + output_layer->channels();
  std::vector<float> output = std::vector<float>(begin, end);

  for (int i=0; (int)i<output.size(); i++)
   std::cout << "Error value:  " << output [i] << std::endl;
```

What could be the reason for negative values ?

Comment: You have two layers with identical names. Is this on purpose?

Comment: yes. this is the exact copy of the prototxt caffe (in `examples/mnist/mnist_autoencoder.prototxt`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems that you used the wrong blob. The network defined in the prototxt produces two output blobs: one is cross_entropy_loss and the other one is l2_error. So net_->output_blobs()[0] may be blob 'cross_entropy_loss'. Second, 'const float* end = begin + output_layer->channels()' statement seems wrong. If you'd like print all the loss for a batch images, you should use output_layer->num(). You can try this.